# Extracting Excel-published tables from a PDF document

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to copy Tables 1,2, and 3 found at the bottom of this PDF file:
http://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/attachments/03-13-Coverage%20Estimates.pdf
into Excel. I've tried Copy+Paste but they've not come out nicely in Excel.
These tables were clearly generated by Excel. Is there any sort of "inverse mapping" -- a way to generate the spreadsheets that generated these Tables?

Thanks.

Comment: How'd you know they were Excel-published?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the table from PDF to Word first, then copy it from Word to Excel. That should get it pretty close for you. **Note:** *depending on what version of Word you are using, you might have to convert the text to a table before copy and pasting into Excel*.